# Implement a Celery Consumer for RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

### What I want to achieve

I have an external producer that sends messages to an RabbitMQ instance to a certain Queue. I want to implement a celery consumer that listens to this Queues and starts a task as soon as RabbitMQ receives a message for those Queues.

### What I did so far

I assured that RabbitMQ actually receives messages and puts them in the correct Queue. I also assured that the Connection to the Broker is set. (I can execute Celery Tasks)

However when I tried to implement the example from the Docs the expected Logs didn't show up.

This is the example:

```
from my_proj.celery import app
from celery import bootsteps

class InfoStep(bootsteps.Step):

    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        # here we can prepare the Worker/Consumer object
        # in any way we want, set attribute defaults, and so on.
        print('{0!r} is in init'.format(parent))

    def start(self, parent):
        # our step is started together with all other Worker/Consumer
        # bootsteps.
        print('{0!r} is starting'.format(parent))

    def stop(self, parent):
        # the Consumer calls stop every time the consumer is
        # restarted (i.e., connection is lost) and also at shutdown.
        # The Worker will call stop at shutdown only.
        print('{0!r} is stopping'.format(parent))

    def shutdown(self, parent):
        # shutdown is called by the Consumer at shutdown, it's not
        # called by Worker.
        print('{0!r} is shutting down'.format(parent))


app.steps['worker'].add(InfoStep)
app.steps['consumer'].add(InfoStep)
```

I start the worker with `celery --app=my_proj.celery:app worker`.

What am I missing? Do I understand the whole bootsteps thing wrong?

---

##Edit:

I tried another way with `bootsteps.ConsumerStep` like so:

```
my_queue = Queue(
    "my_queue",
    Exchange("my_exchange"),
)


class MyConsumerStep(bootsteps.ConsumerStep):
    def get_consumers(self, channel):
        return [
            Consumer(
                channel,
                queues=[my_queue],
                callbacks=[self.handle_message],
                accept=["json"],
            )
        ]

    def handle_message(self, body, message):
        print("Received message: {0!r}".format(body))
        message.ack()


app.steps["consumer"].add(MyConsumerStep)
```

I'm still running into the problem that the messages aren't consumed or acknowledged. I figured out that I can add a consumer by calling `celery --app=my_proj.celery:app controll add_consumer my_queue` that actually seems to consume the messages but I would like to start the consumer without the command line command calling the queue specifically.

Also although the messages are consumed, they aren't processed by the Consumer I wrote. Instead I get the following error:

```
[2022-05-31 12:33:44,720: WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message.  Wrong destination?!?
The full contents of the message body was: (some details to the message)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup but I've defined the queue as an attribute of the consumer class. Not sure if makes any difference here.

```
class MyConsumerStep(bootsteps.ConsumerStep):
    my_queue = Queue(
        "my_queue",
        Exchange("my_exchange", type='topic'),
    )

    def get_consumers(self, channel):
        return [
            Consumer(
                channel,
                queues=[self.my_queue],
                callbacks=[self.on_message],
                accept=["json"],
            )
        ]

    def on_message(self, body, message):
        print("Received message: {0!r}".format(body))
        message.ack()


app.steps["consumer"].add(MyConsumerStep)
```